# select from menu item one is activity to go, how can i go direct activity in android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Activity main contain below cade all work fine , but when i clock on logout from drawer i want to go activity instand fragment , if i put break; in case logout than fragment class not not resolve.

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    Float elevation =   getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.elevation_toolbar);

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.home:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment_.class;
            break;
        case R.id.process:
            fragmentClass = ProcessFragment_.class;
            break;
        case R.id.decline:
            fragmentClass = RejectFragment_.class;
            break;

        case R.id.more:
            try {
                 startActivity(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mndigital")));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/search?q=mndigital")));
            }
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment_.class;
            break;
        case R.id.logout:
            VPreferences.reset();
            Intent intent = new     Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity_.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
  //                fragmentClass = HomeFragment_.class;
 //                break;
          default:
            fragmentClass = HomeFragment_.class;
            break;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    menuItem.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        toolbar.setElevation(0.0f);

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
}
```

when i click logout from drawer login activity open howcan i reach.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a **`break`** after **`case R.id.logout:`**.

It is going to the default case as well when the case is R.id.logout.

Writing **`finish()`** does not kill an activity immediately, but completes the other pending instructions in that thread before finishing.

Or you could just **`return`** the flow of control from the switch block after you have started the *LoginActivity_*.

```
case R.id.logout:
            VPreferences.reset();
            Intent intent = new     Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity_.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break; // to make sure it doesn't go in the default block
            return; // to return the flow of control outside the switch statement
```